# Xamarin Android - deleting item from ListView deletes TWO items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, xamarin, listadapter

I have a project that uses a ListView to list some offers. The ListView is populates with the adapter below.

I've recently added a delete button to the ListView items, which should obviously delete the item from the list. All is good. However, after i delete my first item successfully, the next time i click on a delete button on one of the ListView items, it actually deletes TWO items from the list.

The deleteButton.click event seems to trigger twice, the second time i attempt to delete an item from the list.

You can see i've been playing around with various ways to try and get it working by the various commented code lines i have.

Can anybody help please?

```
    public class OffersAdapter : BaseAdapter<TableItem> 
    {
        Button DeleteButton;

        List<TableItem> items;
        Activity context;

        public OffersAdapter(Activity context, List<TableItem> items)
            : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override TableItem this[int position]
        {
            get { return items[position]; }
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = items[position];

            View view = convertView;

            if (view == null) 
            {

                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.OffersLayoutItem, null);
            }

//          else 
//          {
//              DeleteButton = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.offerDeleteButton);
//              //DeleteButton.SetTag (Resource.Id.deleteButton, position);
//
//          }


            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.company;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text2).Text = item.Heading;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text3).Text = item.SubHeading;
            view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.Image).SetImageBitmap (item.bitmapImage);

            DeleteButton = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.offerDeleteButton);

            //DeleteButton.Tag = position;
            //DeleteButton.SetTag (Resource.Id.deleteButton, position);


         DeleteButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
            {
                DeleteButton.Tag = position;

                Console.WriteLine("position clicked was " + position);

                //int delPos = (int)(((Button)sender).GetTag (Resource.Id.offerDeleteButton));

                items.RemoveAt (position);

                string heading = item.Heading;
                string subheading = item.SubHeading;

                deleteItemFromParse(heading, subheading);
                NotifyDataSetChanged ();

            };

            return view;
        }
```

Comment: why you have commented `DeleteButton.Tag` line ?

Comment: I presume you mean the first one - under the line:

DeleteButton = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.offerDeleteButton);

I've just tried adding it back in, and the same thing happens. It removes two items the second time i click the Delete button.

Comment: see my answer probably help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked in the end. But i thank you for the comments and help.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = items[position];

            View view = convertView;

            if (view == null) 
            {

                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.OffersLayoutItem, null);

                offerDeleteButton = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.offerDeleteButton);

                offerDeleteButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
                {
                    int delPos = (int)(((Button)sender).GetTag (Resource.Id.offerDeleteButton));

                    items.RemoveAt (delPos);

                    string heading = item.Heading;
                    string subheading = item.SubHeading;

                    deleteItemFromParse(heading, subheading);
                    NotifyDataSetChanged ();

                };
            }

            else 
            {
                offerDeleteButton = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.offerDeleteButton);


            }

            offerDeleteButton.SetTag (Resource.Id.offerDeleteButton, position);

            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.company;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text2).Text = item.Heading;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text3).Text = item.SubHeading;
            view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.Image).SetImageBitmap (item.bitmapImage);



            return view;
            }
```